# Sesiones en GuzzleHttp (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, api

Actualmente tengo dificultades para consumir una API que creé. Todo iba bien hasta que llegué a un servicio de la API que crea una sesión; en Postman es creada correctamente, sin embargo, utilizando GuzzleHttp en Laravel para consumir la API me genera el problema de que al parecer no crea o no persiste la sesión, pues al hacer el retorno de la sesión desde la API en la misma clase sí funciona, sin embargo, al intentar ejecutar otros servicios que dependen de que esa sesión esté activa el sistema colapsa.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $response = $this->guzzle->request('POST', 'login', [
        'form_params' => [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ]
    ]);
    var_dump($response);
}
```

El var_dump me devuelve lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entre todo lo que me dio, me interesa que sí está creando PHPSESSID, sin embargo, al consumir un servicio que depende de que exista la sesión (y no ser así interceptará un middleware) genera inmediante conflicto.

¿Alguna ayuda con este tema de sesiones siendo consumidas con GuzzleHttp?
Reitero que en Postman todo funciona correctamente, tal cual como debería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta correcta es que un API debe ser stateless. Debieras refactorizar olvidándote de que existen las sesiones.

La respuesta práctica requiere ir un poco más atrás: entre dos peticiones, PHP puede "recordar" la sesión valiéndose de una cookie. En Postman, el comportamiento por defecto es aceptar cookies y enviarlas en las sucesivas peticiones al mismo hostname. (A menos que explícitamente desactives el cookie-jar)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Guzzle, por el contrario, por defecto una petición será efímera a menos que explícitamente le pases un cookiejar. [Guzzle trae una implementación funcional](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies), que usarías más o menos como:

```
class ApiClient {
        private $client;
        private $cookieJar;

     public function   __construct() {
          $this->cookieJar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();
          $this->guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['cookies'=>$this->cookieJar]);
     }

     public function login(Request $request)
     {
        // la sesión quedará en el cookie jar
        $response = $this->guzzle->request('POST', 'login', [
            'cookies'=>$this->cookieJar,
            'form_params' => [
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password
            ]
        ]);
        var_dump($response);
     }

     public function profile() {
        // El cookieJar enviará el PHPSESSID correspondiente
        $response = $this->guzzle->request('GET', 'profile', [
            'cookies'=>$this->cookieJar
        ]);
        var_dump($response);
     }
}
```

(**Disclaimer**: no me acuerdo si basta instanciar el cliente con la opción cookies o de verdad hay que pasar la llave en cada request... pero es irrelevante para el ejemplo)

Por debajo el cookiejar es poco más que un array, así que puedes json_encodearlo cuando quieras persistir en disco o en caché.